# How to remove one old python installation from a system with multiple (non-system) installations of python

Tags: macos, python

## Disclaimer

First, let me get the obvious out of the way: **I have not touched the system-bundled Python.**  I know it’s important to leave it alone.  I have, in fact, done exactly that. ☺

---

## Background

The Python official releases for Mac have a very handy Installer.  (It’s the Installer’s brilliance that allowed me to put newer versions of Python on my system without screwing up the system-bundled version.  Thanks, Pythonistas!)

Now, my primary Python installation is 2.7.  Since it is the last 2.x release, that’s fine.

However, I was curious to learn about Python 3 as well, so I installed it.  And it plays perfectly nicely with Python 2.  In fact, Python 3 is opt-in, which is just what I wanted.  “Works as advertised.”

## Now, the weird part…

I have 2 installed versions of Python 3!  The installers for Python 3.1 and Python 3.2 both installed to separate locations.  So, now I have Python 3.1 hanging around and I’m never planning to use it.  And since the installer is awesome (I’m not being sarcastic; I’m really impressed, especially since most programming languages require compilation from source), it also creates entries in /Applications with some handy utilities.

But since I have installed a newer Python 2 and two versions of Python 3, this means I now have:

- **/Applications/Python 2.7**,
- **/Applications/Python 3.1**, *and*
- **/Applications/Python 3.2**

## Help Wanted!

I just want to ditch Python 3.1.

And I want to be very thorough about it.  No forgotten directories buried under **/Library/*** (or whatever).

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You should check the installation script for python 3.1 and build an installation file-list. After this do this for the python 3.2 too (you don't want remove files common to both versions.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.4/using/mac.html) noting that they seem to have hard coded 2.5 instead of the current version and is not that well written

> What you get after installing is a number of things:

> A MacPython 2.5 folder in your Applications folder. In here you find
> IDLE, the development environment that is a standard part of official
> Python distributions; PythonLauncher, which handles double-clicking
> Python scripts from the Finder; and the “Build Applet” tool, which
> allows you to package Python scripts as standalone applications on
> your system.

> A framework /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, which
> includes the Python executable and libraries. The installer adds this
> location to your shell path. To uninstall MacPython, you can simply
> remove these three things. A symlink to the Python executable is
> placed in /usr/local/bin/.

so remove

```
/Applications/Python 3.1
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1
/usr/local/bin/python31
```

(I use a different install so this might be python3.1 or similar)